# StartFragment cannot be resolved to a type android error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have just started android programming and still figuring out how fragments and activity works. So I am trying some codes but I am getting the error "StartFragment cannot be resolved to a type"

Here is my code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        //StartFragment cannot be resolved to a type
        StartFragment myfragment = new StartFragment();

        transaction.add(R.id.namefrag, myfragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.view_fragment,myfragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.load, myfragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.store,myfragment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining `StartFragment`?

Comment: If `StartFragment` is defined in a different package, be sure to import it.